# XAML - Changing the background image deletes the textbox

Tags: c#, xaml

I am making a Windows 8 Universal app. In order to make a hover effect, I want to change the background image of a stackpanel. This stackpanel contains a textblock, that disappears as soon as I change the background image.

Here is the C#

```
//Creating a background image
var brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/newprojectblue.png"));
//Adding the background to the panel
panel.Background = brush;

//Changing the color of the text
paneltext.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(1, 255, 255, 255));
```

And here is the XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="panel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="177,250,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Background="#FFEBEFFE" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerEntered="panel_PointerEntered" PointerExited="panel_PointerExited">        
    <TextBlock x:Name="paneltext" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="158,0,31,0" Height="63"  FontSize="30" Width="166" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF4183D7" Canvas.ZIndex="1000" />
</StackPanel>
```

I don't think it is a Z index error.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting alpha to `1`, which is very very transparent (invisible). If you were thinking it's in range `[0.0;1.0]`, then you are [wrong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.fromargb), it's in range `[0;255]`:

```
// wrong
FromArgb(1, 255, 255, 255)

// correct
FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you so much !